# How to pass data between 3 threads that contain while True loops in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, python-multithreading

Im trying to generate data in two threads and get that data in a separate thread that prints the data.
3 threads, 2 threads generate data , 1 thread consumes the data generated.

The Problem: not getting both generated data into the consumer thread

**How can I pass data generated in 2 threads and deliver it in the consumer thread?**

````
#from threading import Thread 
import concurrent.futures
import time
# A thread that produces data 
def producer(out_q): 
        while True: 
            # Produce some data
            global data
            data = data + 2
            out_q.put(data) 
# Another thread that produces data 
def ac(out2_q):
    while True:
      global x
      x = x + 898934567
      out2_q.put(data)  
 
# A thread that consumes data 
def consumer(in_q): 
    while True: 
        # Get BOTH produced data from 2 threads
        data = in_q.get() 
        # Process the data 
        time.sleep(.4)
        print(data, end=' ', flush=True)
x=0       
data = 0
q = Queue() 
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    t1 = executor.submit(consumer, q)
    t2 = executor.submit(producer,q)
    t3 = executor.submit(ac, q)```
````

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to go with `threading.Thread` in this case. Please see the code below and follow comments. Feel free to ask questions.

```py
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue
import time


def producer_one(q: Queue, e: Event):
    while not e.is_set():
        q.put("one")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Producer # one stopped")


def producer_two(q: Queue,  e: Event):
    while not e.is_set():
        q.put("two")
        time.sleep(2)
    print("Producer # two stopped")


def consumer(q: Queue):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        print(item)
        q.task_done()  # is used to unblock queue - all tasks were done
        time.sleep(2)

    # will never be printed ! - since it is daemon thread
    print("All work is done by consumer!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _q = Queue()  # "connects" threads
    _e = Event()  # is used to stop producers from the Main Thread

    # create threads block
    producer_th1 = Thread(target=producer_one, args=(_q, _e, ))
    producer_th2 = Thread(target=producer_two, args=(_q, _e, ))
    # daemon means that thread will be stopped when main thread stops
    consumer_th = Thread(target=consumer, args=(_q, ), daemon=True)

    try:
        # starts block:
        producer_th1.start()
        producer_th2.start()
        consumer_th.start()
        time.sleep(20)

        _e.set()  # ask producers to stop
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        _e.set()  # ask producer threads to stop
        print("Asked Producer Threads to stop")
    finally:
        producer_th1.join()  # main thread is block until producer_th1 is not stopped
        producer_th2.join()  # main thread is block until producer_th2 is not stopped

        _q.join()  # now wait consumer to finish all tasks from queue
        print("Queue is empty and program will be finished soon")
        time.sleep(2)  # just wait 2 seconds to show that consumer stops with main thread
        print("All done!")
```

Comment: Let's say that you want to finish the program when one of the producer threads "the user " enters exit (input()), how can you kill all threads and finish the program when user inputs exit????

Comment: @YusmePraderaMartinez it is not problem at all, use ```try except finally``` blocks, in ```except``` block ask producer threads to stop, they will be stopped immediately, then wait consumer tread to finished already existent tasks (if you do not want to do it, just use ```sys.exit(100)```. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @YusmePraderaMartinez I use ```KeyboardInterrupt``` since the error is associated with users ```Ctrl + C``` input. To stop program I handle standard signal, signals can be handled only in main Thread.

Comment: @YusmePraderaMartinez any feedback please?